# Creating an object detection program using TensorFlow but keep running into what I think is a resource exhaustion problem

Tags: python, tensorflow

When my code gets to the line with model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, validation_data=validation_data, epochs=50, batch_size=8, train_whole_model=True) it runs one Epoch then just returns a "Killed" message and stops
Error Message:

```
Epoch 1/50
2023-06-13 18:24:22.065768: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:368] Loaded cuDNN version 8600
1/4 [======>.......................] - ETA: 1:49 - det_loss: 5.1588 - cls_loss: 1.2843 - box_loss: 0.0775 - reg_l2_loss: 0.0631 - loss: 5.2220 - learning_rate
2/4 [==============>...............] - ETA: 0s - det_loss: 5.1479 - cls_loss: 1.2726 - box_loss: 0.0775 - reg_l2_loss: 0.0631 - loss: 5.2110 - learning_rate:
3/4 [=====================>........] - ETA: 1s - det_loss: 5.9107 - cls_loss: 1.2874 - box_loss: 0.0925 - reg_l2_loss: 0.0631 - loss: 5.9738 - learning_rate:
4/4 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - det_loss: 5.8568 - cls_loss: 1.2811 - box_loss: 0.0915 - reg_l2_loss: 0.0631 - loss: 5.9199 - learning_rate: 0.0088 - gradient_norm: 5.7363Killed
```

Complete Code:

```
import numpy as np
import os

from tflite_model_maker.config import QuantizationConfig
from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import object_detector

import os
from PIL import Image

import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


print("version",tf.version)
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
from absl import logging
logging.set_verbosity(logging.ERROR)

# physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
# tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)


spec = model_spec.get('efficientdet_lite0')
train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    '/tf/ModelMakerOD/images/train00',
    '/tf/ModelMakerOD/images/train00',
    ['Lnotch', 'Mnotch','Rnotch']
)


validation_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    '/tf/ModelMakerOD/images/eval00',
    '/tf/ModelMakerOD/images/eval00',
    ['Lnotch', 'Mnotch','Rnotch']
)

test_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
    '/tf/ModelMakerOD/images/test00',
    '/tf/ModelMakerOD/images/test00',
    ['Lnotch', 'Mnotch','Rnotch']
)
#train_data, validation_data, test_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_csv('gs://cloud-ml-data/img/openimage/csv/salads_ml_use.csv')
model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, validation_data=validation_data, epochs=50, batch_size=8, train_whole_model=True)
model.evaluate(test_data)
model.export(export_dir='.')
model.evaluate_tflite('model.tflite', test_data)
model_path = 'model.tflite'

# Load the labels into a list
classes = ['???'] * model.model_spec.config.num_classes
label_map = model.model_spec.config.label_map
for label_id, label_name in label_map.as_dict().items():
  classes[label_id-1] = label_name

# Define a list of colors for visualization
COLORS = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3), dtype=np.uint8)

def preprocess_image(image_path, input_size):
  """Preprocess the input image to feed to the TFLite model"""
  img = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
  img = tf.io.decode_image(img, channels=3)
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.uint8)
  original_image = img
  resized_img = tf.image.resize(img, input_size)
  resized_img = resized_img[tf.newaxis, :]
  resized_img = tf.cast(resized_img, dtype=tf.uint8)
  return resized_img, original_image


def detect_objects(interpreter, image, threshold):
  """Returns a list of detection results, each a dictionary of object info."""

  signature_fn = interpreter.get_signature_runner()

  # Feed the input image to the model
  output = signature_fn(images=image)

  # Get all outputs from the model
  count = int(np.squeeze(output['output_0']))
  scores = np.squeeze(output['output_1'])
  classes = np.squeeze(output['output_2'])
  boxes = np.squeeze(output['output_3'])

  results = []
  for i in range(count):
    if scores[i] >= threshold:
      result = {
        'bounding_box': boxes[i],
        'class_id': classes[i],
        'score': scores[i]
      }
      results.append(result)
  return results


def run_odt_and_draw_results(image_path, interpreter, threshold=0.5):
  """Run object detection on the input image and draw the detection results"""
  # Load the input shape required by the model
  _, input_height, input_width, _ = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['shape']

  # Load the input image and preprocess it
  preprocessed_image, original_image = preprocess_image(
      image_path,
      (input_height, input_width)
    )

  # Run object detection on the input image
  results = detect_objects(interpreter, preprocessed_image, threshold=threshold)

  # Plot the detection results on the input image
  original_image_np = original_image.numpy().astype(np.uint8)
  for obj in results:
    # Convert the object bounding box from relative coordinates to absolute
    # coordinates based on the original image resolution
    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = obj['bounding_box']
    xmin = int(xmin * original_image_np.shape[1])
    xmax = int(xmax * original_image_np.shape[1])
    ymin = int(ymin * original_image_np.shape[0])
    ymax = int(ymax * original_image_np.shape[0])

    # Find the class index of the current object
    class_id = int(obj['class_id'])

    # Draw the bounding box and label on the image
    color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[class_id]]
    cv2.rectangle(original_image_np, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), color, 2)
    # Make adjustments to make the label visible for all objects
    y = ymin - 15 if ymin - 15 > 15 else ymin + 15
    label = "{}: {:.0f}%".format(classes[class_id], obj['score'] * 100)
    cv2.putText(original_image_np, label, (xmin, y),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)

  # Return the final image
  original_uint8 = original_image_np.astype(np.uint8)
  return original_uint8


INPUT_IMAGE_PATH = "/tf/ModelMakerOD/testimage/slice_00035_z=0.1337um.bmp"
DETECTION_THRESHOLD = 0.3

# Load the TFLite model
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Run inference and draw detection result on the input image
detection_result_image = run_odt_and_draw_results(
    INPUT_IMAGE_PATH,
    interpreter,
    threshold=DETECTION_THRESHOLD
)

# Display the detection result
plt.imshow(detection_result_image)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
plt.savefig("image.png", dpi=700)
```

I though it was a GPU problem at first and i kind of was so i got the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Ti and it helped a little bit as before this it was not even getting past the Load data segment of the code; now it just runs on Epoch. But i'm still having problems